# Operative Temperature in Underfloor Heating?

Tags: heat-transfer, heating-systems

I am new to the Underfloor heating system, and a bit confused on the terminology for Operative Temperature.

Is this the temperature that is measured by the sensor or is this the set-point temperature on the thermostat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may well depend on who did the writing.

The set point is the desired temperature and the sensor should measure the ambient temperature so that it heats, or not, according to where the ambient temperature is wrt to the set point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, different authors use the term differently. I am going through this paper, " Simplified calculation for cooling/heating capacity, surface temperature distribution for radiant floor  [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378778812004306]. I think they are using the operative temperature as the average of AUST and temperature rise because of conductive heat transfer.